# Invalid value (printed as '--') in a numpy array from a netCDF file

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, netcdf

I read netCDF files through `netCDF4` into `python`. 
I get arrays with invalid values that print as `--`, for example:

```
[[[-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]

 [[-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]]
```

Where do these values originate from, and how could I identify (and replace) them? Things such as `numpy.isnan` would return me `--` as result, too. I can use these arrays with `--` later without crash (I can for example plot them), but they seem to be problematic for some operations.

For example, I used to do something like

```
numpy.mean(myarray, axis=(1,2)) # the tuple for `axis` is not very regular
```

on `myarray` originating from my netCDF files before without any problem, but I get `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple` and a crash with these weird `--`-filled arrays...

I am using `python 2.7.9` (and, in case relevant for the printing to screen format, `PyCharm` for code editing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), where `--` represent the masked elements.

Just use`myarray.data` and `myarray.mask` to get the data and the invalid elements, respectively.

Most likely, a masked numpy array was intentionally saved in that netcdf4 file, probably for a reason. So I would simply keep using this masked array as it is. As you noticed, most  Numpy/Scipy/Matplotlib functions (e.g. `numpy.mean`) have a specific logic for handling them.

Comment: Thanks @rth, of course this is indeed a masked array (I was puzzled by the netCDF origin). Thanks - yet I am still getting the error with `numpy.mean` with tuple as axis argument, even though I updated from `1.9.1` to `1.9.2` like you. Still investigating this... ???

Comment: For the `numpy.mean` trouble, I opened a new question as it remains enigmatic to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209624/numpy-mean-used-with-a-tuple-as-axis-argument-works-for-one-typeerror-for

Comment: @ztl No, sorry, I might have make a mistake while running the test, I do get the exception as well when using a tuple for the axis in masked arrays.